# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (Passing username into dash)

Tags: php, laravel

I know its duplicate question but, i dont get the answer to them so i create new

this is `my Controller`

```
if(count($checklogin) > 0)
{

    echo "Success";

    // return redirect('/dashboard')
    // ->with('session_user',   $checklogin);

    return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', $checklogin);
}
else
{
    echo "Login failed";
}
```

This is my blade.php page and my code

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

the error that i got

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: The `{{ }}` are parsed and put thru `htmlentities`. It's basically `echo htmlentities($whatever)`. Long story short, `session('status')` is a an array which is passed into `htmlentities`.

Comment: `{{ }}` cleans the string by default in Blade, and `$checklogin` is not a string but an array. What's in it? Do a `dd($checklogin);`, you probably just want to print a specific key, `->with('status', $checklogin["status"]);`

Comment: so what should i put.

Comment: @Andrew what would be the correct to print out

Comment: Iterate over `session('status')`, cause it's not a string, but an array.
Or, you could do `implode(' ,', session('status'))` to concatenate it as a string

Comment: @JuanPablo what would be the correct?? to echo the result

Comment: You don't echo when using blade. You use the braces `{{ }}`.
Try `{{ session('status')->implode(' ,') }}` or if it doesn't work, `{{ implode(' ,', session('status')) }}`

Comment: @JuanPablo the 2 answer is not working.

Comment: @JuanPablo  i try the blade {{ but it says undefine variable status }}

Comment: if you `{{ dd($checklogin) }}` in the blade file what is returned?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only status message on blade.php ,then you need to pass only status message from your controller.

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', "Your status message here.");
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', $checklogin["status"]);
```

If you want to display complete result received in $checklogin.

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', $checklogin); //In Controller


 @if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
       <?php
           echo "<pre>"; 
           print_r($status);
       ?>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: i want to pass the value of checklogin into my blade. how it may work?? i try your answer but it says undefined status

Comment: Please try with this first. return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', "Your status message here.");

Comment: yes its working if the value is string {{ status }} what if i change the string "your status message here" to $checklogin it doesnt work